Ubuntu 24.04 install on Dell Inspiron 1545 not asking "Erase Disk" question
When trying to install Ubuntu 24.04 on Dell 1545 from USB it asks "Install Ubuntu" and I hit enter. Next I expect the "Erase Disk" question but that never comes.
Originally laptop had/has Windows Vista but seems bogged down with viruses so want to just blow it away and reformat by installing Ubuntu.
SATA is set to AHCI.

That is now an older system. You probably need a lighter weight flavor. https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours
Light weight flavors:
Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Budgie
Flavors of Ubuntu only come with three years of supported life (five years applies to Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server but not flavors)
I have an old 2006 laptop. Ubuntu would not install, server installed & surprisingly Kubuntu installed. But still slow with old HDD. Then tried with my external SSD drive and old laptop was very functional. Still limited on RAM, but as long as not doing too much at once, it worked well.

you can use the Disks utility or gparted to erase the disk after that start the installer. I have the same device and  I installed Ubuntu 24.04

Thanks but how do I use gparted or disk utility if I can get the pc up to do so?
